# java.lang.IllegalStateException: function = <anonymous>, count = 4, index = 4

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-3.1

I am getting this error when I build the project

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: function = <anonymous>, count = 4, index = 4
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerLambdaMemoization.wrapFunctionExpression(ComposerLambdaMemoization.kt:697)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerLambdaMemoization.visitComposableFunctionExpression(ComposerLambdaMemoization.kt:544)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerLambdaMemoization.visitFunctionExpression(ComposerLambdaMemoization.kt:608)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:235)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrFunctionExpressionImpl.accept(IrFunctionExpressionImpl.kt:23)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.transformChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:48)
```

Here are my dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha08'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta06"
```

Jetpack compose used to work fine for me on Artic Fox Canary but when I build my project on Artic Fox Beta 1, I get this error.

Comment: Getting the same error on latest Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 1

Comment: Update all compose dependencies to beta07

Comment: thanks a lot! updating compose to beta07 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update all compose libraries to `beta07`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta07"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta07"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta07"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta07"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01"
```

It would be better to use something like:

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.0-beta07'
}
```

and then:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists with the compose compiler.  It's not just enough to update compose libraries, the compiler needs to be updated to at least beta07 as well.  This is easy to miss as it's not with the list of dependencies and doesn't have lint highlighting in Android Studio (yet).

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-rc01"
}
```